# Improve smooth scrolling in order to get anchor links on the URL Adress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, anchor, smooth-scrolling

As the title says, I Found [this script](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) to get smooth scrolling and improved it a little, now it looks like this:

```
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').on('click', function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50 // in this case 50px BEFORE
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
```

It triggers when the user click on an anchor link.

The problem is that the URL address doesn't change. I'll like to change also the user URL address bar, in order to get the anchor link displayed everytime the user click on the link that makes him scroll.

Thanks in advance for any help you could give me.

PS: you can see the website where I'm testing this [here](http://latanaalquadrato.altervista.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change address using:

```
if (target.length) {
    history.replaceState(null, null, this.hash);
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50 // in this case 50px BEFORE
    }, 1000);
    return false;
}
```

If you want to update browser history, use instead:

```
history.pushState(null, null, this.hash);
```

[More info](https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/)